# Конфликт версий python-а на Ubuntu 14.04: после установки Python 3.5.1, используя checkinstall, перестал работать "Центр приложений"

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, makefile, dpkg

Ubuntu 14.04

**Python 3.5.1** был установлен из исходников ( *./configure ; make ; checkinstall* ).

В итоге перестал работать "Центр приложений", и, наверное, еще много чего.
*aptitude -f install* предлагает удалить кучу пакетов (ну, понятно, тех, которые зависели от **python <= 2.7**).

*/usr/bin/python* ссылается на */usr/bin/python2*. Т.е. с ссылками все нормально (*/usr/bin/python2* на */usr/bin/python2.7*).

Это конфликт пакетов? Как теперь с этим разобраться? И если нельзя разобраться, то как удалить **python3.5** и установить затем без конфликтов?

```
$ aptitude versions python2.7$    
Package idle-python2.7:                    
p   2.7.6-8                                      trusty                   500 
p   2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2                             trusty-security,trusty-u 500 

Package libpython2.7:
p A 2.7.6-8                                      trusty                   500 
i A 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2                             trusty-security,trusty-u 500 

Package libpython2.7:i386:
p   2.7.6-8                                      trusty                   500 
p   2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2                             trusty-security,trusty-u 500 

Package python2.7:
p   2.7.6-8                                      trusty                   500 
i   2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2                             trusty-security,trusty-u 500 

Package python2.7:i386:
p   2.7.6-8                                      trusty                   500 
p   2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2                             trusty-security,trusty-u 500

$ aptitude versions python3$
Package bpython3:
p   0.12-1ubuntu1                                trusty                   500
p   0.12-1ubuntu1.1                              trusty-updates           500

Package diveintopython3:
p   20110517+77958af-1                           trusty                   500

Package ipython3:
p   1.2.1-2                                      trusty                   500

Package python3:
i A 3.4.0-0ubuntu2                               trusty                   500

Package python3:i386:
p   3.4.0-0ubuntu2                               trusty                   500

Package uwsgi-plugin-pyerl-python3:
p   1.9.17.1-5build5                             trusty                   500

Package uwsgi-plugin-pyerl-python3:i386:
p   1.9.17.1-5build5                             trusty                   500

Package uwsgi-plugin-python3:
p   1.9.17.1-5build5                             trusty                   500

Package uwsgi-plugin-python3:i386:
p   1.9.17.1-5build5                             trusty                   500
```

Comment: Выложи выхлопы aptitude versions python3$ и aptitude versions python2.7$

Comment: 1- Никогда не пытайтесь заменить системный питон на Ubuntu руками 2- Если хочется поиграться с разными версиями, можно использовать [`pythonz`](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz) или [`pyenv`](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

скрипт *checkinstall* по умолчанию создаёт файл(-ы) (с суффиксом `.deb`) с пакетом(-ами) **в текущем каталоге**, и устанавливает этот пакет(-ы) при помощи пакетного менеджера вашего дистрибутива (*dpkg*).

поэтому вы можете деинсталлировать этот пакет с помощью того же пакетного менеджера:

```
$ sudo dpkg -r имя-пакета
```

вероятно, имя пакета будет выглядеть как `python3.5`. уточнить имя пакета можно с помощью программы *dpkg-deb*, передав параметром имя файла с пакетом, созданным скриптом *checkinstall*:

```
$ dpkg-deb --info файл-с-пакетом.deb
...
 Package: имя-пакета
...
```

---

скорее всего, после удаления этого пакета, `aptitude -f install` перестанет предлагать «удалить кучу пакетов». но если будет предлагать, приведите, пожалуйста, вывод этой команды прямо в тексте вопроса.

---

вопрос же по поводу того, как правильно собрать пакет, избежав конфликтов и неработоспособности других программ, лучше задать отдельно: он слишком обширен.

---

**дополнение**

раз скомпилированный пакет носит «каноническое» имя `python`, простое его удаление, скорее всего, будет невозможно.

попробуйте переустановить пакет из репозитория:

```
$ sudo aptitude reinstall python
```

если это не поможет (скорее всего, версия установленного вами пакета **выше** версии пакета *python* в репозитории), то попробуйте скачать файл с пакетом и установить его:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/sometempdir
$ cd /tmp/sometempdir
$ aptitude download python
$ sudo dpkg -i python*.deb
```

если и это не поможет (на шаге `aptitude download python`), замените этот шаг «ручным» скачиванием пакета из каталога `pool/main/p/python-defaults/` (например, http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-defaults/). судя по другой приведённой вами информации, вам нужен файл [python_2.7.5-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb](http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-defaults/python_2.7.5-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb):

```
$ wget http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-defaults/python_2.7.5-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

точнее имя необходимого файла можно установить, например, с помощью *apt-cache* (приведён ориентировочный вывод):

```
$ apt-cache policy python
python:
  Installed: 2.7.5-5ubuntu3
  Candidate: 2.7.5-5ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

после скачивания, как и написано выше, его надо установить с помощью *dpkg*.

---

есть ещё один вариант «про запас»:

1. удалите пакет *python* с помощью именно *dpkg* (в этом случае никакие зависимые пакеты не будут удалены):

   ```
   $ sudo dpkg -r python
   ```
2. установите пакет из репозитория:

   ```
   $ sudo aptitude install python
   ```

Comment: Скачал вручную и установил с пом. dpkg . Теперь по команде python открывается 2.7 . Заработал центр приложений. 
Но aptitude -f install все-равно предлагает удалить множество пакетов. И теперь непонятно, куда делся python3.5 . "python3.5 : команда не найдена" . Еще при установке dpkg выдал предупреждение, что не может удалить каталоги(каталоги не пусты, пишет) - /usr/local/share , /usr/local/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m, /usr/local/lib/python3.5,  /usr/local/lib, /usr/local . Это нормально?
И как быть с python 3.5 ? Как его установить теперь ? Или восстановить...

Comment: *Это нормально?* — нет, но после ваших манипуляций с *configure;make;checkinstall* — вполне ожидаемо. если в перечисленных каталогах только остатки от *python*-а — удалите их вручную. // по поводу `aptitude -f install` и правильной установки новой версии *python*-а я вам писал в ответе.

Comment: А Вы можете немного рассказать, что произошло, когда я скачал и установил python (http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-defaults/python_2.7.5-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ? Он по размеру 133Кб. Что-то не похоже на весь интерпритатор с модулями. И куда все-таки делся 3.5 ? Он же не удалялся...

Comment: *что произошло, когда я скачал и установил python* — вы установили из репозитория пакет *python*. список файлов пакета можно посмотреть командой `$ dpkg -L имя-пакета`. *И куда все-таки делся 3.5 ? Он же не удалялся* — вы удалили самосборный пакет *python*, который установили перед этим вместо необходимого в вашей системе пакета из репозитория.

Comment: ясно, спасибо ..

Comment: `# dpkg -r python && apt-get install python` решение лучше на самый верх ответа переместить.

Answer (score 0):

### Решение по установке Python 3.5 :

После конфигурирования, создания **MakeFile** и запуска **checkinstall** (*./configure ; make ; checkinstall*), **checkinstall** предлагает заполнить инфу о пакете :

```
0 -  Maintainer: [ user@host ]
1 -  Summary: [ python 3.5.1 ]
2 -  Name:    [ python ]
3 -  Version: [ 3.5.1 ]
4 -  Release: [ 1 ]
5 -  License: [ GPL ]
6 -  Group:   [ checkinstall ]
7 -  Architecture: [ amd64 ]
8 -  Source location: [ Python-3.5.1 ]
9 -  Alternate source location: [  ]
10 - Requires: [  ]
11 - Provides: [ python ]
12 - Conflicts: [  ]
13 - Replaces: [  ]
```

Что бы избежать конфликтов, нужно во 2-ом и 11-ом пунктах изменить **python** на **python3.5** :

```
0 -  Maintainer: [ user@host ]
1 -  Summary: [ python 3.5.1 ]
2 -  Name:    [ python3.5 ]
3 -  Version: [ 3.5.1 ]
4 -  Release: [ 1 ]
5 -  License: [ GPL ]
6 -  Group:   [ checkinstall ]
7 -  Architecture: [ amd64 ]
8 -  Source location: [ Python-3.5.1 ]
9 -  Alternate source location: [  ]
10 - Requires: [  ]
11 - Provides: [ python3.5 ]
12 - Conflicts: [  ]
13 - Replaces: [  ]
```

Comment: я бы всё-таки рекомендовал воспользоваться уже [собранными пакетами](http://askubuntu.com/a/682875/416190).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, полностью согласен !